# Firebug shows incorrect (possibly hijacked) link CouponDropDown

Tags: hyperlink

This is the first time I saw this... I have text in my code and it says Passport and Visa Requirements. This is my markup

```
<div class="rectangle"><span>Passport and Visa Requirements</span></div>
```

Crazy thing happens on the live server, somehow a link is injected on the word **"visa"**. This is the markup I see in firebug.

```
<div class="rectangle">
<span>
Passport and
<a id="_GPLITA_0" title="Click to Continue > by CouponDropDown" style="text-decoration:underline" href="http://i.txtsrving.info/click?v=" in_rurl="http://i.txtsrving.info/click?v=" in_hdr="">
Visa
<img src="http://cdncache1-a.akamaihd.net/items/it/img/arrow-10x10.png" style="display: inline; vertical-align: super; margin: 0px 0px 0px 3px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; height: 10px;">
</a>
Requirements
</span>
</div>
```

Is my htaccess file not configured properly? How do I deal with this? Is this a security issue?

Comment: Google CouponDropDown virus malware.

Comment: The error might be due to the API of the server on which you're saving the files..nothing else..because many servers would like to add there own settings and configurations to your files. For better service, I think there is a purchase service saying Click to Continue!

Comment: @drixson I didn't vote it down but it's not really a programming question. I reformatted it and gave it an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-coupondropdown

This is probably adware on your computer, affecting your browser. Your website is probably fine.

Comment: it was on my Firefox ... some crap I installed I am sure ... thanks man

Comment: It was a add-ons in firefox the uBlock Origin which cause the problem